# FreeIpa. How to setup specific shell only on 1 host for group of users

Tags: sssd, freeipa

I'd like to set specific shell for group of users only in 1 host. In my environment already installed FreeIpa. In FreeIpa I can change shell for all my hosts, it is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an ID View inside FreeIPA for the host. Unfortunately, ID Views are tied to individual users, and there is no way to apply a view to multiple users based on a group membership, so you will have to set up a separate entry in the view for each individual user.

```
# ipa idview-add my_view
------------------------------------------
Added ID View "my_view"
------------------------------------------
  ID View Name: my_view

# ipa idview-apply my_view --hosts=myhost.example.foo
--------------------------------------------
Applied ID View "my_view"
--------------------------------------------
  hosts: myhost.example.foo
---------------------------------------------
Number of hosts the ID View was applied to: 1
---------------------------------------------

# ipa idoverrideuser-add my_view some_user --shell=/bin/zsh
-------------------------------
Added User ID override "some_user"
-------------------------------
  Anchor to override: some_user
  Login shell: /bin/zsh
```

Note that if the host does not already have a view applied to it, you will need to restart `sssd` after creating it, as `sssd` only checks for the presence of a view on startup.